# What is the "57.29578" that ArcGIS uses in Aspect calculation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, aspect

ArcGIS Desktop Help on [How Aspect works](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-aspect-works.htm) explains the calculations used, but introduces the for me magic number of 57.29578:

```
aspect = 57.29578 * atan2 ([dz/dy], -[dz/dx])
```

Where does this number come from and what does it stand for?

Comment: It took me a while and some research to figure out what was going on, so I thought I'll post a question-answer here, maybe it'll help someone :)

Comment: Nice one, I remember the number 1.852 from mapping software I learnt from as a student. Realizing what it was was very educational and provides a mental shortcut that I use still.

Comment: Cool! Had to look that one up too, but it's great to see all these numbers making sense: 1.852 -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautical_mile

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a GIS **aspect** is generally shown in **radians**.

`57.29578` is **1 radian in degrees** - ArcGIS is using this number when converting to radians.

A simple way to remember how to convert from degrees to radians and vice versa, is to keep in mind that **180° = π rad** (check out the [corresponding section on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/trig-functions/intro-to-radians-alg2/v/introduction-to-radians)) - therefore:

- 1 rad = 180°/π
- 1° = π rad/180

Here's a great visualization that explains this relation well:

[image]

<sup>(Credit - [Lucas V. Barbosa - Own work, Public Domain](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=25112326))</sup>

And here's some python code for converting one way and the other:

```py
import math

def radians_to_degrees(radians):
  """converts radians to degrees."""
  # pi radians = 180 degrees -> 1 radians = 180/pi degrees
  rads_in_degrees = ( 180 / math.pi ) * radians
  return rads_in_degrees

def degrees_to_radians(degrees):
  """converts degrees to radians."""
  # pi radians = 180 degrees -> 1 degree = pi/180 radians
  degs_in_rads = ( math.pi / 180 ) * degrees
  return degs_in_rads
```

Running the code let's us finally (with a drumroll...) reveal the mystery number's identity unambiguously:

```py
print(radians_to_degrees(1))
print(degrees_to_radians(57.29578))

>>>> 57.29577951308232
>>>> 1.0000000084983167
```